# I use Cmake to make project, but it called error when generating : Target "xxxxxxx" links to: igl::core , but the target was not found

Tags: c++, cmake, configuration, compilation, libigl

```
Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "101_GlyphRendering_bin" links to:

    igl::core

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(101_GlyphRendering)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin PUBLIC igl::core igl::glfw igl::opengl tutorials)
```

I opened the project and built it, an error occurred:

```
C1083 Cannot open include file:'directional/directional_viewer.h':No such file or dictory
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXQpY.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is your problem, but speaking of

> C1083 Cannot open include file:'directional/directional_viewer.h':No
> such file or directory

If you want to manually link libraries, you need to also include headers from that libraries. To do such, use

```
target_include_directories(<target> PUBLIC <include_folder_dir>)
```

where `<target>` is your `${PROJECT_NAME}_bin` and `<include_folder_dir>` is folder with headers of library you are linking to.